# Caching on Yii of static files

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii, frontend

I have this stupid problem with Yii where my local dev caches css and js files. When I try edit the file, it doesn't show up the changes, but the fire does get corrupted and breaks everything. This happens for some indiscriminate amount of time and then it fixes itself.

My Yii config is like this for the assetManager:

```
$config['components']['assetManager']['forceCopy'] = true;
$config['components']['assetManager']['appendTimestamp'] = true;
$config['components']['assetManager']['linkAssets'] = true;
```

As you can see below, the JS file just ends after making a small colour change to one of the mouse over fields.

[image: JS file just ends]

The timestamp doesn't seem to be appended to the JS file when including it like all the other resources.

```
<script src="/custom/infobox.js?v=1427807792"></script>
<script src="/js/neighbourhoods-map.js"></script>
<script src="/js/search-block.js?v=1423510537"></script>
```

The file is included by calling registerJsFile() in the view file.

```
$this->registerJsFile('/js/neighbourhoods-map.js', [
    'depends' => ['\app\assets\MapsAsset'],
    'position' => View::POS_END]
);
```

I changed the above to include a timestamp, but the problem is still happening.

```
$this->registerJsFile('/js/neighbourhoods-map.js?v='.time(), [
    'depends' => ['\app\assets\MapsAsset'],
    'position' => View::POS_END]
);
```

This is soooooo frustrating to deal with. Can anyone shed some light on what the issue is here?

Comment: Do u see the timestamp appended to your javascript src? Also u don't need to set linkAssets as "true" unless you are using symbolic links

Comment: @BalajiViswanath - Yeah, it doesn't seem to add it, but it's there for other files. I've added more info to the post.

Comment: Did u try browsers other than chrome to check if this issue exists across all browsers?

Comment: @BalajiViswanath - Yip, problem persists across Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue while I was using Vagrant with nginx.

The solution was to just turn off sendfile directive from nginx configuration.

```
sendfile  off;
```

Comment: Any idea how this might happen with Apache?

Comment: I think I found the equivalent `EnableMMAP off` and `EnableSendfile off`